# Generating caps with Trading Post

Tags: fallout-4

I have always tend to build useful posts such as Weapons for ammo, Clinics and healing/stimpaks etc. But I wonder how efficient can they be if used to generate caps.

So I am asking for three things:

1. Are there any more factors affecting the amount of caps generated except for the tier of the Trading Post and Population size?
2. What is the maximum amount of caps I can generate per settlement per day?
3. What is the maximum amount of caps I can generate per settler assigned to Trading Posts?

Additionally: Does anyone knows how much caps can be stored before Trading Posts generate no more?

Comment: Whatever the answer is, it will pale in comparison to a water farm and setting up all the vendors.  You can easily make about 10k caps if you cram that one settlement with all the unique vendors because their caps stash is different than the generic ones.

Comment: That may be so... but isn't it convenient if you can just drop by every settlement you pass and just pick up some caps as you travel? Also since crafting materials can be used across link settlements that might also means that having caps in the linked workshop may allow me to build more Trading Posts in new settlements when I am still low on caps.

Comment: The "convenience" of this is offset by how you have to find the caps in the workshop stash.  Even without any assignment, settlers will automatically collect junk.  If I'm picking out caps from a giant list of items, why not pick up a stack of purified water and convert it to caps via the vendors?

Comment: True... but as I think about it, generating caps and purified water does not conflict with each other. That means I can have my settlement generate both caps and purified water then sell the water for even more caps $.$

Comment: So for the purpose of this question I'll just focus on generating caps, I am sure there is already a question on making water farms.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually make money using these trading posts for your settlement using 2 methods.

1)  They generate their own caps and place it in the workshop.  (probably less than 500, i have not seen it go over that yet)  I have not tested when they reset to placing this in the workshop.

2)  You can sell items to them.  Depending on your investments this can result in more than 1200 caps per barter.  I invested in every shop I have in Sanctuary.  This usually resets once every 48 hours.

For number 2:

- You might have a water farm.  You get all the purified water then go to your shops and sell them there.
- You might also have bullets you don't use.  You can sell them there.

I can make at the least about 3000 caps (I have tier 3 shops general, weapons, armor, food and clinic) going through the shops every time I visit a settlement.

I made a box besides the workshop where I can transfer all the scraps and other items generated by my settlement.  This way I can sell what I don't need to the shops easily.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been years but I was able to discover how to maximize passive cap income with the least amount of effort.

Settlements are capped at a max of 50 caps per day (1 hour irl) in order to reach this you need 2 level 3 merchant stands of any kind with settlers assigned to them and that will automatically reach max cap production for that settlement.

If we do so some math here, let's say we have 10 settlements with 2 lvl 3 merchants each. That's 50 caps a settlement x 10 settlements. That's 500 caps an hour for doing absolutely nothing. Most people will play the game for 3+ days so we do 500 x 72 hours thats 36,000 caps.

To reiterate, every settlement with 2 lvl 3 merchants will generate 50 caps each. The more settlements you get the more money you can make.

I currently have 20 settlements with 2 stores each and I make 1000 caps an hour by just playing the game and that + water purification I'm nearing 800k caps.

Answer (score 0):

After playing for couple hundred hours, I have never found more than 150 caps in any of my settlements, even in the one with 6 shops (first aid, clothing, weapon, junk, 2 unique vendors).

Comment: I had over $4k once. But no one sells .50 cal ammo 600 at a time, so what's the point. To buy shipments? Yeah, homie don't play Fallcraft.